# Type 'key' cannot be used to index type 'data'

Tags: typescript

I have the error `Type 'key' cannot be used to index type 'data'.`

User, Community, Listing, Comment are all types and the NotificationDataType type is enum

```
type data = {
  [NotificationDataType.USER]: User;
  [NotificationDataType.COMMUNITY]: Community;
  [NotificationDataType.LISTING]: Listing;
  [NotificationDataType.COMMENT]: Comment;
};

export interface SendNotificationOptions<
  T extends Record<NotificationDataType, true>,
> {
  type: T;
  message: string;
  data: {
    [key in keyof T]: data[key]; //error is here
  };
  iconId?: string;
  iconName?: string;
  recepients: string[];
  sendEmail?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`T extends Record<NotificationDataType, true>` allows for keys other than `NotificationDataType` in `T`, thus allowing for a case where `key` is not a valid key for `data`:

```
type Example = Record<NotificationDataType | string, true>;
type Demo = SendNotificationOptions<Example>;
```

In this instance, `Example` is perfectly permitted as generic parameter to `SendNotificationOptions` since it does extend `Record<NotificationDataType, true>`.

However looking at the type this results in, we find that the `key` from `key in keyof T` now essentially is of the type `NotificationDataType | string` and `string` is not a valid index key for `data` which only allows the exact four keys specified. That's why you get an error.